# Collision Map for Unity-2D Top Down

Tags: collision, unity3d-2dtools, topdown

[image]

Is there a way to use an image as the collision data?

The above image shows an overlay for my map which should be able to serve as the collision data.

I am looking to have characters be able to pathfind within the white space and treat the blue space as impassable terrain.

Comment: What do you mean by a collision data? What are you doing?

Comment: I am looking to have characters be able to move around within the white space and treat the blue space as impassable terrain. I would also want pathfinding to work within the white space.

Comment: It is possible but very complicated.